# Form designer cannot be loaded

Tags: c#, designer

I have a project that I am working about a year old. It has been running fine but needs a little love. One of these is to use only x64 on some of the needed libraries.

Now that I have been working on this a bit I cannot load two forms that derive from a base class. This worked before, I am not sure what I did to break this.

My error is:

> The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the
> classes within it can be designed. The designer inspected the
> following classes in the file: Form1 --- The base class
> 'ThermalVision.ExtendedForm' could not be loaded. Ensure the assembly
> has been referenced and that all projects have been built.

My extended for form loads and the design loads just fine. The Extended form is super simple:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ThermalVision
{
    public class ExtendedForm : Form
    {
        public delegate void BroadcastMouseLocation(object sender, EventArgs e);
        public event BroadcastMouseLocation OnBroadcastMouseLocation;


        public void ReceivedMouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MousePointEventArgument mpea = (MousePointEventArgument)e;
            OnBroadcastMouseLocation(this, mpea);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried deleting the Extended for from the project and readding. I do see other solutions out there but they seem not related to this issue.

Comment: The ReceivedMouseHover Handler invokes the Handler for Event OnBroadcastMouseLocation. Check whether it is being subscribed to before invoking.

Comment: if(OnBroadcastMouseLocation != null) OnBroadcastMouseLocation(this, mpea);

Comment: @MarkBenningfield - Wow. Yes, that did. That's kinds a PITA.